# Magento2 can't call custom phtml fail in CMS Static Block

Tags: magento2, phtml, static-block

I have tried many ways to call the custom phtml file in Static Block but none of them seems to work.

My file is located - **app/design/frontend/Magento/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/extra/test_view.phtml**

How i call the file in CMS Static Block -

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_view" template="Magento_Theme::extra/test_view.phtml"}}
```

And when i add the static block to main content area, it just displays the code thats above. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: it is because you are adding code in `wysiwyg editor` enable. When you add code disable editor first

Answer (score 1):

Your file should replace from 
`app/design/frontend/Magento/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/extra/test_view.phtml`

to

`app/design/frontend/Magento/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/extra/test_view.phtml`

Comment: still same issue, it displays code instead of content of file.

Comment: give screen what is outputed

Comment: This is my directory screen - https://prnt.sc/mj9wse Homepage - https://prnt.sc/mj9xjt Static BLock - https://prnt.sc/mj9ya1

Comment: https://prnt.sc/mja00k - if u did mean inspect element. here u go.

Comment: @Kara How you are display your static block?

Comment: I'm new to magento , where can i see that Petrov? I think its default.

Comment: What is Petrov? What is default?

Comment: Can i help you with teamviewer?

Comment: Yes you can, how can i send u the details?

Comment: i don't know, private messages is does not exist here.

Comment: Do you have discord ? Or ill just post the details here, and delete them afterwards.

Comment: Do you have discord ? - no.  Or ill just post the details here - ok.

Comment: i can't launch teamviever in my home laptop, sorry

Comment: well , i guess ill be stuck with this haha

Comment: can you share your display in skype?